# ASP.NET MVC The required anti-forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

I get this error in my login form:

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

I am using the default project of ASP.NET MVC generated with visual studio 2015 template.

Login.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...
}
```

AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    ...
}
```

Machine Key definition in web.config:

```
<machineKey validationKey="6237432C07086CE1A8FAAD3CC71A3AC1DE0B22DE9061D7CAF798E5B18E6E888D7A3F88004D0A928952CB81598ED565B26F8175E30294B1F5A1F3220229163F1C" 
    decryptionKey="E61A22E8DEE09CB4640B2863705CE6BC95E64C8797CAB8CAE7463BE7F9AB1B94" 
    validation="SHA1" 
    decryption="AES" />
```

Generated HTML page:

```
<form action="/Account/Login" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Ei4E03S5nvvdR9N2KJg8aGDQK9fI3xbBJLJzT3z3c7QAyyxbGf11ncmTAiD-8itHoKWYuNNghOsmyTS2hBDlmkv7Ttk1" />
```

I have a cookie in my browser with name `__RequestVerificationToken` and value `qM5XwYIQiiHk2lumHWcXHOPPji2VptN95X0FDLneyXSN3_sGrF6fe7zt8KHC5MjopQoBh9sJl5vEJLGOAzy1h-8R-nk1` that expires on session end: `When the browsing session ends`.

This errors is not happening on local with `IIS Express`, but after I deployed project to a server, this error occurred.

Clearing cookie and restarting browser did not solve the issue.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I removed anti-forgery token from both controller and view and found something strange: form submits data without any problem but somewhere between submitting and validation, all fields become null or empty. `__RequestVerificationToken` became null before validation and this causes the problem. Now I am investigating on this new problem :(

Comment: please show us your sent request to server. right click on page inspect element -> network tab

Answer (score 2):

In Your Web.config find `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />`property and comment it out , or set up You project to always Use SSL.